# Converting the JDE Date format to DB2

Tags: db2

I want to convert a JDE time value stored in the database as numeric(6) and I want to convert it to a time value in ibm DB2 either using a format or a time conversion?

Eg  JDE time value = 130313
The result I expect is 13:03:13  (Hours, minutes, seconds)

Dates are Ok I can use
SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1

But time I think is just formatting the value from 6 numbers to a hour:minute:second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have TIMSEP set to ':', you could use

```
    time( insert(insert( digits(dec( jdedate ,6,0)) ,5,0,':'),3,0,':') )
```

But I suggest

```
    timestamp_format( digits(dec( jdedate ,6,0)) ,'HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: You may not need the inner `dec()`, since your date is already numeric(6,0).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_timestampformat.htm) function:

```
SELECT TIME(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('130313', 'HH24MISS'))
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```